# Converting java to kotlin, for a next and previous button

Tags: java, android, kotlin

```
@Override
    public void onClick(android.view.View v) {
        if (v == next) {
            viewFlipper.showNext();
        }
        else if (v == previous) {
            viewFlipper.showPrevious();
        }
    }
```

I'm trying to create a next and previous button on android studios using Kotlin, I found the code in java and would like to know how to convert it into kotlin. I've spent the whole day trying to figure it out, please help

Comment: IntelliJ/AS can do this for you; is there a specific issue? The Kotlin will be nearly identical.

Comment: I tried to convert it but it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   @Override fun onClick(v: View) {
        if (v === next) {
            viewFlipper.showNext()
        } else if (v === previous) {
            viewFlipper.showPrevious()
        }
    }
```

Comment: No @ in front of override in Kotlin.  It's a keyword, not an annottion.  And its lower cased

Comment: The showNext and Previous are java functions and need to be removed I think.https://gist.github.com/yuosefamro/94064de1025581ea0034f32ac403873dThis is the link of the code I found

Comment: @KTH1230 But they’re being called?